# Get clicked element onclick

Tags: javascript, onclick

```
var submenus = document.getElementsByClassName("submenu");
for (var i = 0; i < submenus.length; i++) {
    submenus[i].onclick = function() {
        toggle(submenus[i].nextSibling);
        return false;
    }
}

function toggle(el) {
    if (el.style.display == 'block') {
        el.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        el.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Causes error: `TypeError: submenus[i] is undefined`

I assume `submenus[i]` is not in the scope of the function. How do I get the element clicked so I can toggle it's next sibling?

Comment: What makes you think `submenus` is an array?

Comment: Can you setup a fiddle

Comment: Your problem isn't with `submenus`, it's with the index which is equal to `submenus.length` for all your handlers. See @jbabey's link.

Answer (score 6):

```
var submenus = document.getElementsByClassName("submenu");
for (var i = 0; i < submenus.length; i++) {
    submenus[i].onclick = function() {
        toggle( this.nextSibling);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Inside such an event handler the `this` keyword is bound to the element, that triggered the event. So in your example you can use `this` to refer to you submenu item and thereby to its sibling.

For more information see the link @FelixKling provided: http://quirksmode.org/js/this.html

Comment: Well... This is simpler that what I did... +1

Comment: Some explanation could be useful though. http://quirksmode.org/js/this.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
var submenus = document.getElementsByClassName("submenu");
for (var i = 0; i < submenus.length; i++) {
    (function(e){
      submenus[i].onclick = function() {
        toggle(e);
        return false;
      }
    })(submenus[i].nextSibling);
}
```

The immediately called function creates a scope in which `submenus[i].nextSibling` is kept.

Answer (score 0):

It has to look like this:

```
  var submenus = document.getElementsByClassName("submenu");
    for (var i = 0; i < submenus.length; i++) {
        (function(i){
            submenus[i].onclick = function() {
                toggle(submenus[i].nextSibling);
                return false;
            };
        })(i);
    }

    function toggle(el) {
        if (el.style.display == 'block') {
            el.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            el.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var submenus = document.getElementsByClassName("submenu");
for (var i = 0; i < submenus.length; i++) {
    submenus[i].onclick = (function(j) {
        return function () {
            // alert(j);
            toggle(submenus[j].nextSibling);
            return false;
        };
    })(i);
}
```

---

Because `onclick` function will fire after your `for` loop, so whenever the user click
on desired element, the `i` will be the `length` of your elements:

```
<div class="submenu">Hello</div>
<div class="submenu">Hello</div>
<div class="submenu">Hello</div>
<div class="submenu">Hello</div>
<div class="submenu">Hello</div>
<div class="submenu">Hello</div>
```

And with your code:

```
var submenus = document.getElementsByClassName("submenu");
for (var i = 0; i < submenus.length; i++) {
    submenus[i].onclick = function() {
        alert(i);
    }
}
```

You'll get `6` for `i` on every element (check the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6dWA2/1/)).

You must keep `i` inside the `onclick` function, **closure** will help you:

```
for (var i = 0; i < submenus.length; i++) {
    submenus[i].onclick = (function(j) {
        return function () {
            alert(j);
        };
    })(i);
}
```

As you see, I've created a function and execute it immediately (with a parameter I've called it `j`, and the value of it, for each element, is the `i`).
The return of it, is another function.
Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6dWA2/2/).